# jQuery parent div sort

Tags: jquery, html, sorting

I have simple HTML data:

```html
<div class="divTable svc-adv" id="info">
    <div class="divTableBody adv-body">
        <div class="divTableRow adv-row">
            <div class="divTableCell adv-cell snmhdr">Title</div>
            <div class="divTableCell adv-cell stitlehdr">Service Name</div>
            <div class="divTableCell adv-cell snhdr">Service Number</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="divTable svc-adv servicealert">
    <div class="divTableBody adv-body">
        <div class="divTableRow adv-row">
            <div class="divTableCell adv-cell advtitle">WAS</div>
            <div class="divTableCell adv-cell advsnm">ABC</div>
            <div class="divTableCell adv-cell advsnum">123</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="divTable svc-adv servicealert">
    <div class="divTableBody adv-body">
        <div class="divTableRow adv-row">
            <div class="divTableCell adv-cell advtitle">NYP</div>
            <div class="divTableCell adv-cell advsnm">XYZ</div>
            <div class="divTableCell adv-cell advsnum">321</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When a user clicks on `snmhdr` class it should sort `advtitle` class data and display `adv-row` in sorted order.

How can I achieve this using jQuery?

Answer (score 2):

I have made few changes in your HTML structure. Added the div's needed to be sorted inside a container id div and also added class Sort-block to div's needed to be sorted.

```
    <div class="divTable svc-adv" id="info">
        <div class="divTableBody adv-body">
            <div class="divTableRow adv-row">
                <div class="divTableCell adv-cell snmhdr">Title</div>
                <div class="divTableCell adv-cell stitlehdr">Service Name</div>
                <div class="divTableCell adv-cell snhdr">Service Number</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
    <div id="container">
        <div class="divTable Sort-block svc-adv servicealert">
            <div class="divTableBody adv-body">
                <div class="divTableRow adv-row">
                    <div class="divTableCell adv-cell advtitle">WAS</div>
                    <div class="divTableCell adv-cell advsnm">ABC</div>
                    <div class="divTableCell adv-cell advsnum">123</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="divTable Sort-block svc-adv servicealert">
            <div class="divTableBody adv-body">
                <div class="divTableRow adv-row">
                    <div class="divTableCell adv-cell advtitle">NYP</div>
                    <div class="divTableCell adv-cell advsnm">XYZ</div>
                    <div class="divTableCell adv-cell advsnum">321</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Jquery Code:

```
var $divs = $("div.Sort-block");
$('.snmhdr').on('click', function () {
    var alphabeticallyOrderedDivs = $divs.sort(function (a, b) {
        return $(a).find(".advtitle").text() > $(b).find(".advtitle").text();
    });
    $("#container").html(alphabeticallyOrderedDivs);
});
```